# put the code in a different file and then "include" it?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, file, include

In my vb.net project, there are tons of buttons and various items. I would like to keep this code in the form1.vb file. One specific button tough, executes a very long piece of code. What I would like to do is put this code in a different file and then "include" it inside the button. I was thinking of a class, but it looses the connection to all the global variables and the stuff needed for that code. I do not really NEED to put this in a different file, its just something that sits there, that i will not look at again and being so long its in the way. Is there a way to put this in a different file and then include it sort of like it is done in php? I am on visual studio 2015 community edition

Comment: http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/partclses.htm

Comment: It could call a method, the method could be at the bottom of the form/class source file, then put it inside a `#Region  "Long code that I dont want to see"` block to collapse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a partial class such as this:

```
Partial Public Class Form1
    Private Sub doStuff()
        Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("This is where your long code should go")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Partial classes add more functionality to your class but they can be contained in a seperate file.

http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/partclses.htm